# Error during boostrap: Stream failed

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax

I'm trying to add a new node to my existing Cassandra cluster which is running AWS EC2. I've configured the cluster name, the seed node and the listen_address in my cassandra.yaml. When I start the cassandra service the seed node is properly found but upon getting a share of the data an Java exception occurs:

`Error during boostrap: Stream failed`

Any idea what is causing this and how I could solve this? Simply doing it again is no solution :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams can fail due to either a networking problem or an sstable corruption. Grep your logs for the stream-id to get more details.

Something like this should help:

```
$ cat system.log| grep "0fb1b0d0-8fc9-11e5-a498-4b9679ec178d" | sed -E 's/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/Source/'|awk '{ split($3,a,":"); $2=a[0] ; $3=""; $4=""; print }'|uniq -c
```

You should run this both on the source and target ends of the stream to get the underlying reasons for the stream failures.

- If the stream failed for networking reasons you'll just have to try
  again.
- If the stream failed due to an sstable corruption, run scrub for that
  sstable at the source node and try again.
- If you almost finished your bootstrap but not quite (most of the data
  streamed over), you may want to bring the node up with
  autobootstrap_false (in the c* yaml) and repair the rest of the way.

This [post](http://www.sestevez.com/cassandra-repair-logs/) I wrote is about repairs but it also includes stream troubleshooting and is relevant in the context of bootstrapping.